# How to downgrade from Gnome Shell 3.6.1?

Tags: gnome

When I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, I didn't know it would upgrade my gnome shell version to 3.6.1. Now, all my extensions are useless. Is there any way to revert back to the previous version?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only solution is to reinstall 12.04 and/or ask to extension developers to upgrade their extensions.